# Date String to Milliseconds

Tags: java, android

I have a time string like 4:52 pm. I want to convert it in milliseconds for comparison with current time of system. How is it possible in android ?

Comment: Easy ton find on google ...

Comment: You should really learn googleing and reading APIs....

Answer (score 3):

```
long millis = 0;
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
try {
      Date d = dateFormat.parse("4:52 PM");
      millis = d.getTime();
} catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String someTime = "4:52 pm";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
Date date = sdf.parse(someTime);
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```